# How can I make controller ports round for my "Lego Gamecube"

Tags: building, design, stickers

[image]

[image]

Found my wife's old 2001 "Nintendo Gamecube" and then it sparked an idea. Once I was done it looked very nice but I still feel there is something missing! How can I make round controller ports?

Comment: Hi Nerd, this is really a nice MOC. However, without a specific question, this post will be closed.

Comment: Thank you very much @Aziraphale and i will fix up this question in no time

Comment: But what am i supposed to change?

Comment: There's no real question here to answer, and the whole situation is opinion based. Some people may already say your creation looks good to be considered final, while others may state a billion of items that are still wrong.  I find it best to discuss such creation in LEGO focused forums or groups.

Comment: Maybe it is a good time to reread https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask .

Comment: @Alex i know, i want it to be opinion based because with all these diffrent questions, i can creat better designs so please dont close this question

Comment: @Nerd I hear what you are saying, and I agree that this would provide helpful feedback for you. Unfortunately, it isn't well suited to our community as we're looking for questions that will produce objectively correct answers. This could be shared on numerous other platforms to solicit the sort of general feedback you are looking for. If you really want to engage with our community, you might try a specific building technique question such as: "How could I alter this MOC to use more authentic round controller ports?"

Comment: Ok thanks, is it ok if i use that comment and put it as a question and for my next question can i use what you said but instead of round controller port put opening lid

Comment: Sure. With your recent edit, this certainly feels like a question that can generate concrete answers.

Comment: Hi @Nerd - would it be possible to split this into two questions - you've got a great answer to the question in the title (How do I make round controller ports), and then we can try and answer the "how do I combine these with a sloped/rounded front".

Comment: thanks @Zhaph-BenDuguid to responding  i can do that

Comment: Could you please tell me hot to phrase this so i dont get my qustion closed

Comment: If you've managed to rework the front to include the holes build by jncraton, then something like "how can I create the rounded front on my LEGO GameCube?" and then take the last two pictures you've included here to demonstrate what you're after.

Comment: Umm... @Zhaph-BenDuguid it actualy wont let me ask a question, it says, "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more." i dont know why? But if its such a problem i can just go on Youtube and search my problem.

Comment: Nerd That error usually appears when you make too many bad questions. I remember that you made multiple low-quality questions about your MOC that all got a negative score, thus triggering this error. You also made a few extremely low quality answers that were obvious guesses, which also add to an answer ban too. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/736547

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to end this ban or something?

Comment: I won't answer that question, that FAQ i linked already provides an obvious answer. Please read it throughly and don't dash through it as if it's rubbish.

Comment: Rubbish? Your from england?

Comment: And i will read through it!

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps something like this using 1x4 arches could work?

[image: Final build]

This does work out to being 2 modules too wide for 1:1 scale with a GameCube, but the trade-off in accuracy may be worth it to you to get the round ports. It appears to be only 1 module wider than your current design.

Here's more detail of the build steps:

### Step 1

[image: step 1]

### Step 2

[image: step 2]

### Step 3

[image: step 3]

### Step 4

[image: step 4]

### Step 5

[image: step 5]

### Final Build

[image: Final build]

Comment: Actualy thats a great idea i could atualy use that but do you see how the actual gamecube slopes. Look at the picture i now added to my question

Comment: If you can find a way to combine this with the sloped edge then i think it will look good

Comment: and its also the perfect size

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd match that curve while keeping the other details intact. I'd certainly love to see an answer that does this, though. You might be able to get a better look by having this extend only a half module out from the front instead of the full module you used in your original design.

Comment: i did do that though

Comment: I will add another picture showing proof

Comment: @Nerd I'm suggesting having it extend only a half module (10 LDU) instead of a full module (20 LDU).

Comment: half module instead of full module ok

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to build it rotated by 90°, ([Tile, Round Corner 2 x 2 Macaroni](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=27925&name=Tile,%20Round%20Corner%202%20x%202%20Macaroni&category=%5BTile,%20Round%5D#T=C) for the holes, perhaps) and use [Slope, Curved 4 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=93606&colorID=86&in=A) to round the edges off?

Comment: @Chronocidal I considered that (along with Macaroni Tiles), but I at least don't have parts in my collection to square up the round outside edge of that part to bring it back to square with the rest of the front panel.